# How to stop users from viewing saved passwords in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, passwords

There's a function in Chrome called "Manage saved passwords":

```
chrome://settings/passwords
```

This allows you to view all the passwords you have saved into Chrome (and new ones get added in there when you allow Chrome to remember a password).

I want to be able to set it up so that any saved passwords cannot be viewed by users, at least not without entering some kind of master password (such as the admin password to the PC or something).

Is there any way to do this or something similar through a workaround? Hell, I'd even be OK with disabling the feature completely (in such a way that it can't be enabled again unless a password is entered).

Comment: (Why) Are users sharing a login account?

Comment: Well, we want to give our employees access to company accounts like eBay, Facebook, Amazon, etc, so they will be sharing those accounts, but we don't want to give them the passwords to said accounts. As I said in another comment we're using an external password manager to achieve this, but there's no point in using that if users can simply circumvent that by prompting Chrome to remember the password inputted by the password manager and then viewing the saved passwords in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

There are several dozen registry settings for Chrome, where you can disable many things, one of them the **Password Manager(*.

If you lock these settings in by removing write access to the respective keys for non-admins, users cannot change them back.
Find or create `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome\PasswordManagerEnabled`, and set it to (DWORD) `00000000` to disable.
There is also "ImportSavedPasswords" (same path), and some others.

Comment: Thanks for the response!

This didn't work. I don't have much experience editing the registry. Did I do it right? http://imgur.com/a/ej8Ku

Comment: I have little knowledge of the details either, but it looks correct to me. My company sets this to `0`, and it removes the whole password manager (and I hate it). I spent hours finding it out, and when I set it back to `1`, it is available again. Maybe it only works with other keys in conjunction... sorry I can't tell. I would expect there is an official documentation for the Chrome registry entries; try to google  it.

Answer (score 0):

One of the Chrome policies you can configure is a [URL blacklist](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/7532419?hl=en). This can include `chrome://` URLs. I haven't tried your specific request but I've seen it done with `chrome://history` so I expect it to work. Of course, if you block access to the manager, they could still save passwords, they'd just be unable to view or delete them on the management page.

Answer (score -3):

Check this post it tells how to configure this option - http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/view-chromes-saved-passwords-anywhere-stop/

Comment: Thanks for the response! I'm afraid none of that helps me.

The reason I'm asking this is because it's part of an upgrade I and the rest of the IT department are doing to our company's security. We want to allow our employees to access company accounts (eBay, Facebook, etc) using an external password manager called LastPass. This will allow them to log into those accounts without knowing the passwords, which is an important security measure for us.

Unfortunately, unless we find a way to disable allowing Chrome to remember passwords, they will always be visible to employees.

Comment: Hello!  Link-only answers are a no-no.  Please include pertinent information directly in your answers, and cite any sources as required.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 - There is no worth while information on `makeuseof.com` its your typical click-bait website.